# Merging arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with a bunch of 1 - 10 results, i need to find a way to merge the two, I am new to php so I may need some help

```
Array
(

[906] => Array
    (
        [id] => 906
        [form] => DJ Form
        [date] => 2013-12-04 16:41:07
        [timestamp] => 1386193267
        [email] => 
        [data] => Array
            (
                [#1] => kaskade
                [#2] => armin van buren
                [#3] => kap slap
                [#4] => avicii
                [#5] => calvin harris
                [#6] => dada life
                [#7] => nicky romero
                [#8] => swanky tunes
                [#9] => eric prydz
                [#10] => bingo players
            )

    )

[905] => Array
    (
        [id] => 905
        [form] => DJ Form
        [date] => 2013-12-04 16:39:52
        [timestamp] => 1386193192
        [email] => 
        [data] => Array
            (
                [#1] => steve aoki
                [#2] => steve aoki
                [#3] => steve aoki
                [#4] => steve aoki
                [#5] => steve aoki
                [#6] => steve aoki
                [#7] => steve aoki
                [#8] => steve aoki
                [#9] => steve aoki
                [#10] => steve aoki
            )

    )
```

)

I want to be able to combined these to get a new array resulting like so:

```
[data] => Array
            (
                [#1] => steve aoki
                [#2] => steve aoki
                [#3] => steve aoki
                [#4] => steve aoki
                [#5] => steve aoki
                [#6] => steve aoki
                [#7] => steve aoki
                [#8] => steve aoki
                [#9] => steve aoki
                [#10] => steve aoki
                [#1] => kaskade
                [#2] => armin van buren
                [#3] => kap slap
                [#4] => avicii
                [#5] => calvin harris
                [#6] => dada life
                [#7] => nicky romero
                [#8] => swanky tunes
                [#9] => eric prydz
                [#10] => bingo players
            )
```

also i need to strip all the spaces and change things like "&" to "and", does anyone know of a good way to do this I need some help! PLEASE SO help me out!

Comment: Do you need to preserve the numbers #1 - #10?

Comment: no thats not neccessary

Comment: Have a look at `array_column` in PHP.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Don't forget to put the link! http://php.net/array_column

Comment: undefined function array_column()

Comment: @user2820604, Seems like your PHP version is less than 5.5 :(

Comment: The official documentation has a link to a shim for array column: github.com/ramsey/array_column

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

```
$result = array()
foreach($inputs as $input){
  $result = array_merge($result, array_values($input['data']));
}
```

$result=str_replace('&', 'and', $result);

Answer (score 0):

Lajos Veres answer in a practical example:

```
<?php
// The result array containing one or more results
$results = array(
    906 => array(
        'id' => 906,
        'data' => array(
            0 => 'One',
            1 => 'Two',
            2 => 'Three'
        )
    ),
    907 => array(
        'id' => 907,
        'data' => array(
            0 => 'Four',
            1 => 'Five',
            2 => 'Six'
        )
    ),
);

echo "<pre>".print_r($results, true)."</pre>";
```

The above would output:

```
Array
(
    [906] => Array
        (
            [id] => 906
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => One
                    [1] => Two
                    [2] => Three
                )

        )

    [907] => Array
        (
            [id] => 907
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Four
                    [1] => Five
                    [2] => Six
                )

        )

)
```

Lajos Veres' code:

```
// Create a temporary array
$tmp = array();

// Loop through the results
foreach ($results as $array)
{
    // Merge the current $array['data'] with the $tmp array
    $tmp = array_merge($tmp, array_values($array['data']));
}

echo "<pre>".print_r($tmp, true)."</pre>";
```

The above will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => One
    [1] => Two
    [2] => Three
    [3] => Four
    [4] => Five
    [5] => Six
)
```

So anything contained in the ['data'] key of each result will be merged together into one big array.